# Upgrade Fails With No Usable Error

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Civi 5.31 in WordPress version 6.0.2 to 5.53. I am using the CV utility from the command line to complete the upgrade.

When I run the upgrade it shows "Upgrade DB to 5.48.1 : SQL" and then more than a line of dots and then fails.

The error shown is:

Task can not execute correctly. The wrong dispatch policy is active. Expected to find "upgrade.finish"

There are no other errors or messages given.  I would appreciate any ideas on how to suss out more information to figure out why this failing.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some discussion about older versions of `cv` having trouble with 5.53. If you can upgrade `cv` and then you're still having trouble, you might want to chime in on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3840.

Comment: I have used the web interface and the upgrade worked as expected. I have not been able to upgrade CV and test as such.